# Is a bad practice mixing function code with preprocessor directive?

Tags: c++, windows

In my C++ project I need to use a "TEST mode".

Normally there are processes that need to be spawned by other processes. Because it's a bit tricky to debug an application started by another application, I need this test mode that basically allocate a console, simulate the presence of other processes creating random data and so don't need to use the IPC facilities.

I started to use preprocessor directive in the code, like:

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(...) {
#ifdef TEST_MODE_ON
   AllocConsole();
   ...
#endif
...
#ifdef TEST_MODE_ON
   FreeConsole();
   ...
#endif
}
```

but I think this is not the best way from the code readability point of view. Is this a bad practice? (why?) Are there any other better ways? Thanks!

Comment: Please, don't use `TCHAR` and its ilk unless you are porting ancient Windows programs.

Comment: Yes, I'm porting some really old code on windows 8, but I don't see the link with my question. BTW why I should avoid the use of tchar?

Comment: Did you take a look at `<assert.h>`?

Comment: You are using `_tWinMain`, that's why I added the comment about `TCHAR`.

Comment: It's by default on VS2013, but I still don't understand what's the point, sorry.

Comment: The trouble is when you use `TCHAR`, you are saying this may be expecting `char` or `wchar_t` and I don't know which (that also means your code will be unportable), but actually you only ever try for one of them. There are myriad subtle and not-so-subtle places the difference is crucial, and getting it wrong results in varous (partly hiden run-time) errors.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, thanks.

Comment: Just use `wMain` and `wchar_t` for string types. Unless you're planning on writing code for Windows 98.

Comment: Or you have much file/socket input/output, or might want to port it, or ... (in which cases you use UTF-8 internally AND externally, aside from system calls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not necessary a bad practice, just makes the code more unreadable. I would go with something like a method caller macro which depending on `TEST_MODE_ON` evaluates to something else:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef TEST_MODE_ON
#define DEBUG_CALL(x) x;
#else
#define DEBUG_CALL(x)
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    DEBUG_CALL(printf("Hello"));
}
```

(Yes, I know it's ugly and unsafe, but nevertheless works)

and of course your compilation takes care of defining `TEST_MODE_ON`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common way to solve this type of problem.  It's a bit mode readable to write:

```
#ifdef TEST_MODE
// ...
#endif
```

as `TEST_MODE` being defined infers that it's `ON`.